# Number of spots in CMB map

Tags: cosmology, cosmic-microwave-background

Is it possible to estimate the number of hot and cold spots of average diameter of 1° in a full-sky map of the CMB? (A full-sky spherical surface has 4pi sr or 41253 sq°). And does this number correspond approximately to the number of superclusters in the observable universe?